# Problem with python packages and tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a directory struture like that:

```
project
|  __init__.py
| project.py
| src/
    | __init__.py
    | class_one.py
    | class_two.py
| test/
    | __init__.py
    | test_class_one.py
```

Which project.py just instantiate ClassOne and run it.

My problem is in the tests, I don't know how to import src classes. I've tried importing these ways and I got nothing:

```
from project.src.class_one import ClassOne
```

and

```
from ..src.class_one import ClassOne
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better directory structure?

----- EDIT -----

I changed my dir structure, it's like this now:

```
Project/
|   project.py
|   project/
    |   __init__.py
    |   class_one.py
    |   class_two.py
    |   test/
        |   __init__.py
        |   test_class_one.py
```

And in the **test_class_one.py** file I'm trying to import this way:

```
from project.class_one import ClassOne
```

And it still doesn't work. I'm not using the executable project.py inside a bin dir exactly because I can't import a package from a higher level dir. :(

Thanks. =D

Comment: Which dir are you in when you run the tests?

Comment: In the test dir, is this wrong? =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your python path.  The easiest way to achieve what you're wanting to do here is to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to where the "project" directory resides.  For example, if your source is living in:

```
/Users/crocidb/src/project/
```

I would:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/crocidb/src
```

and then in the test_one.py I could:

```
import project.src.class_one
```

Actually I would probably do it this way:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/crocidb/src/project
```

and then this in test_one.py:

```
import src.class_one
```

but that's just my preference and really depends on what the rest of your hierarchy is.  Also note that if you already have something in PYTHONPATH you'll want to add to it:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/crocidb/src/project:$PYTHONPATH
```

or in the other order if you want your project path to be searched last.

This all applies to windows, too, except you would need to use windows' syntax to set the environment variables.

Comment: Further info:  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: It worked! I just had to add my project's dir to the PYTHONPATH. Thank you. =D

Answer (score 0):

From [Jp Calderone's excellent blog post](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html):

> Do:
>
> - name the directory something related to your project. For example, if your
>     project is named "Twisted", name the
>     top-level directory for its source
>     files Twisted. When you do releases,
>     you should include a version number
>     suffix: Twisted-2.5.
> - create a directory Twisted/bin and put your executables there, if you
>     have any. Don't give them a .py
>     extension, even if they are Python
>     source files. Don't put any code in
>     them except an import of and call to a
>     main function defined somewhere else
>     in your projects. (Slight wrinkle:
>     since on Windows, the interpreter is
>     selected by the file extension, your
>     Windows users actually do want the .py
>     extension. So, when you package for
>     Windows, you may want to add it.
>     Unfortunately there's no easy
>     distutils trick that I know of to
>     automate this process. Considering
>     that on POSIX the .py extension is a
>     only a wart, whereas on Windows the
>     lack is an actual bug, if your
>     userbase includes Windows users, you
>     may want to opt to just have the .py
>     extension everywhere.)
> - If your project is expressable as a single Python source file, then put it
>     into the directory and name it
>     something related to your project. For
>     example, Twisted/twisted.py. If you
>     need multiple source files, create a
>     package instead (Twisted/twisted/,
>     with an empty
>     Twisted/twisted/__init__.py) and place
>     your source files in it. For example,
>     Twisted/twisted/internet.py.
> - put your unit tests in a sub-package of your package (note - this means
>     that the single Python source file
>     option above was a trick - you always
>     need at least one other file for your
>     unit tests). For example,
>     Twisted/twisted/test/. Of course, make
>     it a package with
>     Twisted/twisted/test/__init__.py.
>     Place tests in files like
>     Twisted/twisted/test/test_internet.py.
> - add Twisted/README and Twisted/setup.py to explain and
>     install your software, respectively,
>     if you're feeling nice.
>
> Don't:
>
> - put your source in a directory called src or lib. This makes it hard
>     to run without installing.
> - put your tests outside of your Python package. This makes it hard to
>     run the tests against an installed
>     version.
> - create a package that only has a __init__.py and then put all your code into __init__.py. Just make a module
>     instead of a package, it's simpler.
> - try to come up with magical hacks to make Python able to import your module
>     or package without having the user add
>     the directory containing it to their
>     import path (either via PYTHONPATH or
>     some other mechanism). You will not
>     correctly handle all cases and users
>     will get angry at you when your
>     software doesn't work in their
>     environment.

Comment: Nice tips, but I still have problem importing a package in a higher level.